# Shortest number of attempts to solve this issue

Tags: calculation-puzzle, weighing

There are 9 identical balls but only one of them has a higher weight. You are also given a weight balance. How many attempts would you require to identify the ball with the extra weight and how?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_puzzle contains the puzzle and generalized explanations for larger sets.

Answer (score 4):

Classic puzzle, you need

> 2

You do this by

> Measuring a set of three versus a set of three.
>  The set with the heavy ball is identified. (The heavier set on the scale, or, if they are equal, the set not on the scale)
>  
>  Weigh two of the balls in said set of three, same thought process. Heavier on the scale, or the one left over if they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think

> 2 steps.

Solution:

> Divide the balls into three gropus of three. Weigh two groups first. 
>  Now weigh any two balls of the heavier group (if both the groupare of
>  same weight, the third group). You will know which one is the heavier
>  ball.